# no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver in Mac OS 10.12.2

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, serial-port, rxtx

I am developing an application in Java using Eclipse IDE. My os is Mac OS 10.12.2 . My application is using the RXTX library (gnu.io.*) for serial communication, added in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.rxtx</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxtx</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I have added also `librxtxSerial.jnilib` file in project by doing this (project->Properties->java buld path->addjars). whenever I run my code it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:83)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the location of the folder that contains `librxtxSerial.jnilib` as *Native library location*:

1. **Right-click** project and choose ***Properties***
2. In ***Java Build Path***, in the ***Libraries* expand the *RXTX* JAR node**
3. Select the subnode ***Native library location: (None)*** and click ***Edit***
4. **Enter the folder location** that contains `librxtxSerial.jnilib` and click ***OK***